# Has there ever been a case where someone wished a theorem or important result wasn't named after them? Has it happened more than once?

Tags: naming-conventions

The current answers to the Academia HNQ [Should I ask for permission to name a mathematical theorem?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/181409/69206) include the following (small excerpts):

> There is no need to ask permission, and mostly likely they will be happy to have the theorem referred to with their names.

and

> I suppose there is no formal need to ask for permission, but
>
> 1. I see no harm in doing so.
> 2. I see the potential for harm in not doing so.

The first can be loosely paraphrased as "go for it" and "it would be bad if you didn't" but the second seems like excellent advice.

I thought I'd ask here if there are any examples that might inspire words of caution as expressed in the 2nd answer, so I'd like to ask:

**Question:** Has there ever been a case where someone wished a theorem or important result wasn't named after them? Has it happened more than once?

Comment: I haven't found an ideal "X named-after Y" tag so I've improvised with tagging.

Comment: _I wonder if this kind of answering is a bit cavalier and perhaps too opinion-based even for Academia SE._ - This is a question for the meta site.

Comment: @Kimball this question as asked here is fine where it is. I don't have a meta question about the Academia SE answers; I'm just explaining my motivation; why I'm asking this question here. Since answers in the other site were not fact-based, I've come to ask here, where fact-based answers can be found.

Comment: The only case that I can imagine if when the theorem is wrong, and then your error gets known as "Kirmse's mistake" or "Lame's flawed proof" etc.  Normally people are upset that a result isn't named after them.

Comment: @Kimball I don't have any idea where to find statistics either way. Where does "Normally people are upset that a result isn't named after them." come from, just a guess? Or has this been established in some documented, quantitative way?

Comment: There is something in information theory called "Mrs Gerber's Lemma", named (without permission) after a living person who made no technical contribution to its formulation or proof.  I do not know if she ever knew about this.

Comment: @kimchilover indeed! https://mathoverflow.net/q/398029

Comment: I wouldn't call this an important result, but the [Parker square](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aOT_bG-vWyg&feature=youtu.be) springs to mind nonetheless.

Comment: @uhoh And a google search shows me there is even a Mr Gerber's Lemma.  I suppose (conventionally at least) if there is a Mrs Gerber there must have been a Mr Gerber, too!

Comment: A near-miss rather than an answer, but the Alpher–Bethe–Gamow paper only included Bethe as a coauthor for the sake of the pun, and while Bethe seems not to have minded (pace a rumour that he considered changing his name when the theory was "on the rocks"), Alpher was apparently rather dismayed that Bethe's name was included as it threatened to overshadow his genuine contribution. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpher%E2%80%93Bethe%E2%80%93Gamow_paper#Bethe's_name

Comment: @ruakh yes I see what you mean, I've made an edit and adjusted my introduction. Thank you for calling this to my attention!

Comment: Well, [Gregori Perlman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grigori_Perelman) rejected the Fields Medal, the European Mathematical Society prize and the only Millenium Prize ever awarded.  I suspect that he would also not be happy to have some things named after him either.

Comment: FYI after looking at the current answers, I don't think there are any counterexamples to the idea that people aren't happy with having a theorem _that they proved_ named after them.  (And for the record, I qualified my statement with "most likely".  Yes there are weird situations, but they are unlikely.)

Comment: @Kimball: Sometimes having something called the "John Q. Smith Theorem" early in Mr. Smith's career may result in people associating him exclusively with that theorem, to the exclusion of any past or future work for which person might prefer to be known.  I think late John Conway, for example, viewed his "Game of Life" in such fashion.

Comment: potentially related: [Are there any mathematical objects that got renamed over time?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/14267/3869)

Answer (score 36):

On the Löwenheim–Skolem theorem:

> It is somewhat ironic that Skolem's name is connected with the upward direction of the theorem as well as with the downward direction:
>
> "I follow custom in calling Corollary 6.1.4 the upward Löwenheim-Skolem theorem. But in fact Skolem didn't even believe it, because he didn't believe in the existence of uncountable sets." – Hodges (1993).
>
> "Skolem [...] rejected the result as meaningless; Tarski [...] very reasonably responded that Skolem's formalist viewpoint ought to reckon the downward Löwenheim-Skolem theorem meaningless just like the upward." – Hodges (1993).
>
> "Legend has it that Thoralf Skolem, up until the end of his life, was scandalized by the association of his name to a result of this type, which he considered an absurdity, nondenumerable sets being, for him, fictions without real existence." – Poizat (2000).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem#Historical_notes

Answer (score 14):

According to a [recent episode of *PBS Space Time*](https://youtu.be/6mJXv5OBel8), Freeman Dyson "regretted" the [Dyson Sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_sphere) being named after him.

According to the Wikipedia article

> Dyson was not the first to advance this idea. He was inspired by the 1937 science fiction novel Star Maker, by Olaf Stapledon,...

The PBS episode states that Dyson referred to the concept as the *Stapledon Sphere* as Dyson was trying to "avoid having his own name attached to the idea".

Comment: Definitely a nice answer to the spirit of the question (as the OP confirms) — but perhaps worth noting it isn’t really an answer to the question as written, since it’s a concept/invention, not a “theorem or significant result”.

Answer (score 8):

I cannot easily document the chatter about it, but G. ("Beppo", for "Giuseppe") Levi in 1906 used what we'd now call a "Sobolev space", to prove an actual (=true) minimum principle for certain vector spaces of functions. (Thus, actually giving a true, and, mercifully, sufficient version of "Dirichlet's principle" (about existence and uniqueness of a maximizing vector...) for most applications.)

The story I'd heard is that "the French" referred to such spaces (in French) as "the spaces of Beppo Levi", and pronounced in such a way that was somehow degrading to Levi.

Apparently, Levi objected to this... and, since the rest of Levi's life he worked on other things, his name was removed from such reference, and now it's "Sobolev spaces". There are various pseudo-historical accounts of how Sobolev came to agree to that renaming, etc. I cannot vouch for any of that, etc.

Comment: Thanks, now I want to ask in [French SE](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions) "How can 'the spaces of Beppo Levi' be translated into French, then pronounced in such a way that it would somehow sound degrading to Levi?" but I'm too shy.

Comment: @uhoh, I gather (not easily documentable) that somehow that current pronunciation of "les espaces de Beppo Levi" was somehow annoying to him... Long time ago... :)

Comment: I can imagine it. I'm quite comfortable living in my own private Idaho, off "in space" by myself for example, but perhaps other people might feel uncomfortable with the imagery

Comment: @uhoh The French could have pronounced the name with the accent on the final syllable and would have also probably not pronounced the double _p_ of Beppo (as much as many foreigners do not pronounce the double _s_ in my name). So, they could have pronounced it as _Bepò Levì_. I wouldn’t have found it annoying, but people can be annoyed by much anything.

Comment: @uhoh: I am French and tried to pronounce that the "wrong" way (even loud, to the surprised look on my wife's face). I have no idea how it can sound bad.

Comment: @WoJ thank you for the experimental results! :-) I don't think it would have flown well as an SE question.

Comment: @paulgarrett Being french, I really don't see why "les espaces de Beppo Levi", even sounded "à la française", without emphasis on the double "p" and with accent on the final syllables, as Massimo Ortolano says, could be conceived as degrading. Could you elaborate, please ?

Comment: @Alfred, I was told so by an Italian whose judgement I trust on this, and who'd prefer not to be named. :) But, personally, I have absolutely no real idea. Something about the way "Beppo" was pronounced.

Comment: @paulgarrett Well, I trust you about the trustworthy character of your Italian. But however much I wrack my brain I cannot iamgine any way to pronounce "Beppo" with "espaces de" before and "Levi after". Even mispronouncing "espèce de" (which would be a good way to start an insult, yes) instead of "espace de" still does not work on "Beppo"

Comment: @paulgarrett Well, I trust you about the trustworthy character of your Italian. But however much I wrack my brain I cannot iamgine any way to pronounce "Beppo" with "espaces de" before and "Levi after". Even mispronouncing "espèce de" (which would be a good way to start an insult, yes) instead of "espace de" still does not work on "Beppo"

Answer (score 7):

[Diffie–Hellman key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange#Name) is not a case where a person wishes it weren't named after them *per se*, but it is a case where they are unhappy that it is named after them while excluding another contributor:

> In 2002, Hellman suggested the algorithm be called
> Diffie–Hellman–Merkle key exchange in recognition of Ralph Merkle's
> contribution to the invention of public-key cryptography (Hellman,
> 2002), writing:
>
> "The system...has since become known as Diffie–Hellman key exchange.
> While that system was first described in a paper by Diffie and me, it
> is a public key distribution system, a concept developed by Merkle,
> and hence should be called 'Diffie–Hellman–Merkle key exchange' if
> names are to be associated with it. I hope this small pulpit might
> help in that endeavor to recognize Merkle's equal contribution to the
> invention of public key cryptography."

Answer (score 6):

Let me tell two anecdotes related to the question:

1. Once during a seminar talk Hilbert asked: "What is a Hilbert space?"
2. Arnold, apparently envious for so many things named after Anosov, once proposed the term "Anosov's jet" (струя Аносова, in Russian) Anosov's reaction is not recorded, but everyone was sure that he was not happy:-)

Remark. Sometimes a term containing a name can be indeed ridiculous,
for example look at the title of this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/0904.1403. As far as I know, Devaney was not offended:-)

Comment: Why was Anosov unhappy with something being named "Anosov's jet"?

Comment: @nick012000 From what I know of Russian, it seems like the joke was that "струя Аносова" is a homophone of "струя носова" ("я" is pronounced like "ya"), which means something like "nasal stream"/"nasal jet" (sneeze of snot).

Comment: Regarding the Hilbert anecdote: James Yorke says he does the same thing with *Li–Yorke chaos.* However, his concern is more that the respective work is not about defining chaos rather than being unhappy about being named for it. So he more objects to the *chaos* part of the term than the *Yorke* part.

Comment: @nick012000 : Because the Russian words "струя Аносова" can also be translated as "Anosov's stream" and strongly imply "Anosov's urine stream".

Answer (score 5):

A near miss that I found is [Lewis Fry Richardson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_Fry_Richardson#Pacifism), from Wikipedia: "According to Thomas Körner, the discovery that his meteorological work was of value to chemical weapons designers caused him to abandon all his efforts in this field, and destroy findings that he had yet to publish."

Perhaps some other exists who published first and then found that their work had applications that they found objectionable after it was too late--I found Richardson by searching for mathematicians who were also peace activists, but you could search the other way by finding named theorems which were used for especially objectionable things.

Answer (score 5):

There's a story, weakly cited on his wikipedia page (citation goes to a specific page in a book which doesn't seem to back it up, but I can't read the next page in the google books preview so maybe it's there) that Paul Dirac referred to what everyone else calls "Fermi-Dirac statistics" as "Fermi statistics", and "for reasons of symmetry" called the other type "Bose statistics" instead of "Bose-Einstein statistics".

I've also heard a story that I can't back up at all (and so is possibly apocryphal) that whenever someone would refer to Rabi cycles or the Rabi frequency in a conference, if he was in the audience he would stick his hand up and ask what they meant until they explained it in basic terms which didn't include his name.

Both of these are examples of alleged humility (though you could argue about how humble slowing down a talk is) rather than any dismay about the discoveries themselves.

Comment: Dirac had a reason not to use the term "Fermi-Dirac statistics". Please see my answer at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/297183/origin-of-fermi-dirac-distribution?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

S.S. Chern resisted calling Chern classes by name for the longest time.  He eventually gave in with a comment to the effect that everyone calls them by that name, so he should start too.  I read the latter in one of his expository papers but cannot find it at the moment.  Chern was a very humble man.

Comment: I once attended a talk by [Berkovich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Berkovich) about what he called "analytic spaces". People with more knowledge in the field quickly assured me that if I want to read up on that, everyone else calls them [Berkovich spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkovich_space), and would refer to something different and/or more general when talking about "analytic spaces".